# What trigonometric identity makes the method of triangulation work?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, triangulation

I've read [the article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation), but I don't get how to construct the relationships between sides and angles to reach a solution for the distance between two points.

All the other sites I read either just tell you to scale the triangle in a piece of paper or they use a right-angled triangle (making one of the angles you measure be 90 degrees).

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the section titled "Calculation" in that Wikipedia article? Did it make sense? If not, which step(s) did you not understand? (This information should be in your question itself, not a comment; click "edit" to put it there.)

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed enough. I don't understand the very first line of the "calculation" section. Why do we conclude L=d/tan(alpha) + d/tan(beta)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the figure, $x = AB, y = AD, z = AC, h = CD$, where $\overline{CD}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$.

[image: Triangulation Example]

A common application of triangulation: You want to measure the distance from $A$, where you are to a distance object $C$. So you move over a known distance $x$ (usually much smaller than the distance to $C$) to another point $B$ where you can see both $A$ and $C$, then measure the angles at $A$ and $B$ (which I will denote by the same letters).

So you know the angles $A$ and $B$, and the distance $x$. And you want to find $z$. By the Angle-Side-Angle theorem, $A,B, x$ are enough to completely determine the triangle. Drop the height from $C$ onto $\overline{AB}$ intersecting in $D$. $y$ is the distance from $A$ to $D$, which means that the distance from $B$ to $D$ is $(x - y)$. Now we have two right triangles. Since the tangent is opposite over adjacent, we have two expressions for $h$:

$$h = y\tan A \qquad\text{and}\qquad h = (x - y)\tan B$$

Equating these and solving for $y$ gives:
$$y = \frac {x\tan B}{\tan A + \tan B}$$
The left triangle also gives $y = z\cos A$, or $z = \frac y{\cos A}$. Therefore $$z = \frac {x\tan B}{\cos A (\tan A + \tan B)} = \frac{x\sin B}{\sin(A + B)}$$

So from the three measurements you made locally, you are able to compute the distance to the far off point $C$.

Comment: Ah, that's a very clear explanation. Thank you!

It seems I was making a mistake just setting up the problem. I thought we needed to find distance h and not z, cause that's what it looked like from the wikipedia example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation#/media/File:Triangulation-boat.png ). Is that way wrong then?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with finding $h$ instead of $z$. It is just a different problem. I gave an example where the information being sought was the distance from $A$ to $C$. If you need a different measurement, then obviously, you would need to do something a little different. One can find $h$ by multiplying $z$ by $\sin A$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article actually does imply that you want the distance from $A$ to $C$. It just doesn't give an explicit formula for it.

Comment: Also, you can get the same result for a general triangle more simply from the Law of Sines (also see the Law of Cosines, which is good for other related calculations). But based on your question, I thought it better to show how it is calculated directly from right triangles.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, once I know one of the sides, then finding h is trivial. Man, I'm slow to catch these things. And I appreciate you not using the law of sines, this is just more intuitive I guess.

So thanks again! 

Oh, and I'm unsure which answer I should mark as correct... both you and David were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You ask, concerning the Wikipedia article,
"Why do we conclude $\ell =d/\tan(\alpha) + d/\tan(\beta)$?"

Rather than draw yet another figure, let me just note that $d$ in the
Wikipedia article is the same as $h$ in the figure in Paul Sinclair's answer;
$\alpha$ is the angle at $A$, and $\beta$ is the angle at $B$.

In Paul's figure, the point $D$ divides the segment $\overline {AB}$
(which has length $x$)
into two pieces of lengths $y$ and $x - y$ respectively.
This gives us (quoting from that answer),
\begin{align}
h &= y\tan A, \\ h &= (x - y)\tan B.
\end{align}

Equivalently,
\begin{align}
y &= \frac{h}{\tan A}, \tag 1\\ x - y &= \frac{h}{\tan B}. \tag 2
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
x = y + (x - y) = \frac{h}{\tan A} + \frac{h}{\tan B}, \tag 3
$$
that is, segment $\overline {AB}$ consists of two pieces that are
legs of right triangles with angles $A$ and $B$, respectively,
and the lengths of those legs can be determined by trigonometry.
This is the same as the equation you asked about except for the labeling
of the figure: compared to the figure in the Wikipedia article,
Equation $(3)$ uses $x$ for the length $\ell$
and $A$ and $B$ for the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Wikipedia did not explicitly state Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$.
Apparently we are supposed to infer them from the figure and write
the results directly into Equation $(3)$.

Once you have the length of $\overline {CD}$, you can use that, the
known angles, and the sine function to determine the
lengths of $\overline {AC}$ and $\overline {BC}$.
The Wikipedia article seems to assume you can set up the formulas;
it does not give them explicitly.

Comment: Ah, I see now! I hadn't realized the distance was constructed by the sum of y and (x-y). Thought having the y around wouldn't let me carry on with any calculation. Seems next time I should think harder about it. 

Thanks so much for your help!